# How to replace single hyphen with other text such as double hyphen?

Tags: def

I want to replace `-` with `--`. I am able to replace `\\` with `--` using the following code:

```latex
{\def \\ {--\ } #3}
```

but if I try:

```latex
{\def - {--\ } #3} %Option 1
{\def- {--\ } #3} %Option 2
{\def-{--\ } #3} %Option 3
{\def - {{--\ }} #3} %Option 4
```

or any combination of the above, it causes

```
Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
                \inaccessible
    l.77         \begin
                   {rItemize}
```

in the part of the `.tex` file:

```latex
    \begin{rESubsection}
        {text}
        {text}
        {\def \\ {--\ }{Start Date \\ End Date}}
        \begin{rItemize} % here
            \item text
        \end{rItemize}
    \end{rESubsection}
```

ChatGPT did not help even if it gave a running code. I tried all above code on different compilers versions of `pdflatex` (2022, 2021, 2020) but to no avail.

Here is a full minimal working `.tex` file on `pdflatex` compiler version 2020 (legacy) on overleaf as per comments request.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation

\usepackage{xparse} % used for any mmooo...

\usepackage{enumitem} % For rItemize left margin
\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins
%\usepackage[margin=0.4in]{geometry}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{rSubsection}{mmmo}{
  \textbf{#1}, {#2}\IfValueT{#4}{, \textit{#4}}. \hfill {\def \\ {--\ } #3}
  \par
}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{rItemize}{
    \begin{itemize}
      \raggedright
}{
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Professional Experience   
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{rSubsection}
        {Role}
        {Company Name}
        {Date - Date}
        [Location]
        \begin{rItemize}
            \item Text.
        \end{rItemize}

            \begin{rSubsection}
        {Role}
        {Company Name}
        {Date \\ Date}
        [Location]
        \begin{rItemize}
            \item Text.
        \end{rItemize}
    \end{rSubsection}
    \end{rSubsection}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: It's unlikely that ChatGPT is helpful in any case involving TeX: its answers are usually plainly wrong. Anyway, `\def-{...}` is not going to work. Please, add a full minimal example, because `rESubsection` is not a standard environment.

Comment: @egreg Hope this is what you asked for

Comment: you can't define a character unless it is active (like `~`) and you can not (easily) make `-` active without breaking its use in numbers and lengths, or tikz syntax

Comment: just use your editor to fix the source, do not use tex definitions here

Comment: Your minimal example isn't correct:  `\NewDocumentEnvironment` needs 4 arguments!  In your example the second argument with the `<arg spec>` is missing (it can be empty for `ritemize` but it needs to be there otherwise LaTeX will complain about an invalid `\begin` as argument specification.

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle has written:  in principle it is possible to make `-` an active character and then define this active character to get replaced by 2 inactive `-` characters - if you don't know how to define a macro where the same character is active and non-active  it is better to avoid it because it will break to many things.

Comment: The other problem is that you have to make the `-` character active _before_ (La)TeX will read and tokenize the text with the `-` because the tokenization will fix the character's category codes.  (In your code the `rSubsection` environment reads the text with the Date-Date as third argument thus within the environment replacement any category code changes will be too late.

Comment: What's preventing you from inputting `2020 -- 2022` instead of `2020 \\ 2022`?

Comment: At the end of the day, isn't that a search & replace job for the text editor of your choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace something define low level TeX macros using delimited arguments.

For example

```
\newcommand{\replaceminus}[1]{\doreplaceminus #1-\relax}

\newcommand{\docreplaceminus}{}% ensure that this helper macro isn't defined yet
\def\doreplaceminus#1-#2\relax{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax
    #1%
  \else
    #1--\doreplaceminus#2\relax   % replace next - (or remove additional -)
  \fi}
```

The macro `\replaceminus` can then used inside your shown `rSubsection` environment replacement begin text to replace every `-` in the third argument `\replaceminus{#3}`.

The helper macro `\doreplaceminus` assumes an argument with a minus character token (non-active, category code other) and `\relax` as end of the argument.  The macro `\replaceminus` is defined to provide these two tokens as default.  In a first step it is checked if we reached these two tokens, i.e., argument `#2` is empty, and we are finished.  Otherwise the `-` is replaced by two minus character tokens and everything starts anew.  (The macro uses recursion!  To avoid input stack overflows if there are two many minus characters you have to use some well known tricks like `\def\EndFi#1\fi{\fi #1}` to make the macro expansion end recursive.)

Please be aware of spaces in your input and your macros/environment definitions!  My macro `\replaceminus` doesn't add or remove spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's preventing you from inputting

```
date -- date
```

if you want that. Anyway, you can “normalize” the input.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation

\usepackage{enumitem} % For rItemize left margin
\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins

\NewDocumentEnvironment{rSubsection}{mmmo}{%
  \par
  \textbf{#1}, {#2}\IfValueT{#4}{, \textit{#4}}.\hfill\parsedates{#3}%
  \par
}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{rItemize}{}
  {\begin{itemize}\raggedright}
  {\end{itemize}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\parsedates}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \s* (\c{\\}|\-)+ \s* } {\ --\ } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Professional Experience   
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% double hyphen with spaces
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date -- Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% double hyphen with no spaces
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date--Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% double hyphen with one space
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date-- Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% double hyphen with one space
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date --Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% single hyphen with spaces
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date - Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% single hyphen with no spaces
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date-Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% single hyphen with one space
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date- Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% single hyphen with one space
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date -Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% double backslash with spaces
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date \\ Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% double backslash with no spaces
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date\\Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% double backslash with one space
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date\\ Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

% double backslash with one space
\begin{rSubsection}
  {Role}
  {Company Name}
  {Date \\Date}
  [Location]
  \begin{rItemize}
    \item Text.
  \end{rItemize}
\end{rSubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the output is always the same.